# Пролистать страницу в WebView через код

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, webview, android-webview

Всем привет. Такой вопрос: возможно ли пролистать сайт в webView через код и там зафиксировать. Так как на сайте есть форма которую надо заполнить, а она находится внизу и чтобы пользователю не гадать что где, сразу пролистать на форму и зафиксировать. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: А почему бы не вырезать кусок с формой из страницы и отобразить его в WebView?

Comment: вот можно и так, а не могли бы по подробнее рассказать как можно такое провернуть?

Comment: Android то тут при чём? Это делается стандартными средствами js.

Comment: Просто у меня нет доступа к самому сайту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пролистать можно используя метод `scrollTo`, а зафиксировать отключив дальнейший скрол. Думаю, сделать это можно примерно так:

```
// скроллим в конец страницы
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         view.scrollTo(0, view.getContentHeight());
     }
});

// отключаем возможность скрола для пользователя
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!